# Searching Mysql database with multiple keywords

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to search a database for one or multiple keywords passed in `$_POST['search']`, I am not able to loop through the keywords.

The code was modified from https://code-boxx.com/php-mysql-search/

My script is:

```
$str = $_POST['search'];
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $str);
$totalKeywords = count($keywords);
$query = "";
$i = 0;
while($keywords[i] != null)
{
    $query .= " AND name LIKE %".$keywords[i]."%" ;
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (?) ". $query ." ");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['search']]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Ideally the search should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (Keyword1 Keyword2 Keyword3) AND name LIKE '%Keyword1%' AND name LIKE '%Keyword2%' AND name LIKE '%Keyword3%
```

The search page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  require "2.php";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    <!-- [SEARCH RESULTS] -->
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
      if (count($results) > 0) {
        echo $sql;
        foreach ($results as $r) {
          printf("<div>%s</div>", $r['name']);
        }
      } else {
        echo "No results found";
      }
    }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: what's the result of your script above?

Comment: @Dharman the OP is actually using prepared statement functions, the appropriate would be _please use prepared statements properly_ lol

Comment: @Ilham Syahru Ramadhan The script will run "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (?)" but will not add "AND name LIKE" statement

Comment: @Kevin, I am learning. If you have a suggestion to improve the script, I will appreciate it.

Comment: @MoussaEl-hallak try to print the $query (echo $query) if it has the correct value already then you should use the prepared statement properly as the other said. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Thank you @Ilham Syahru Ramadhan, I tried "echo $query" but nothing is passed. I will work on the prepared statement and edit my post. The actual code was modified from https://code-boxx.com/php-mysql-search/

Comment: @MoussaEl-hallak I think, there's might be something wrong with your loop. change it to `while($keywords[$i] != null)` and `$keywords[$i]` inside the assignment of $query, then add `$i++` below $query line

Answer (score 2):

When you use prepared statements, avoid directly injecting your values into the query statement. You'll defeat the purpose of having them prepared.

So, first you can treat you statement into two parts.

One is the `match against`, and two is the `where like` part.

So first build off the base query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1=1"; // base query
```

From there you can append the match against and where like clauses as you go along with the construction.

Then, create the match against bit:

```
MATCH (name) AGAINST (Keyword1* Keyword2* Keyword3* IN BOOLEAN MODE) // the ideal query
MATCH (name) AGAINST (? ? ? IN BOOLEAN MODE) // convert to question mark placeholders
```

To create it, just simply implode (glue) the question marks with spaces according to the number of input:

```
$against_placeholder = implode(' ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, '?')); // = ? ? ?
```

And to create the where like clause:

```
(name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?) // = like keyword1 or like keyword2 or like keyword3
```

So in your code:

```
$like_placeholder = implode(' OR ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, 'name LIKE ?'));
```

So to piece them all together:

```
$against_placeholder = implode(' ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, '?'));
$like_placeholder = implode(' OR ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, 'name LIKE ?'));
$sql .= " AND MATCH (name) AGAINST ({$against_placeholder}) AND ({$like_placeholder})"; // build the query with placeholders
```

This will yield a complete query statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1=1 AND (MATCH (name) AGAINST (? ? ? IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?)
```

And then the rest is just building the actual payload in the execution. Here's the rest:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1=1"; // base query

$against_placeholder = implode(' ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, '?'));
$like_placeholder = implode(' OR ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, 'slug LIKE ?'));
$sql .= " AND (MATCH (slug) AGAINST ({$against_placeholder} IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR ({$like_placeholder})"; // build the query with placeholders
// prep input
$against_keywords = array_map(function($value) {
    return "{$value}*";
}, $keywords);

$where_keywords = array_map(function($value) {
    return "%{$value}%";
}, $keywords);
$keywords = array_merge($keywords, $where_keywords);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($keywords);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you, Kevin, for the answer. This seems to work with one keyword. If there are multiple keywords I got "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?) AND name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?' at line 1' in " I tried to look for a solution but was not successful

Comment: If I use three keywords the I got this " '? ?) AND name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?' at line 1"

Comment: @MoussaEl-hallak I do believe using both match and like makes no sense. you should choose one.

Comment: @MoussaEl-hallak how is the payload delivered into the code? is the input something like this? `$str = "dog cat horse";`? anyway i made some changes

Comment: and as YCS said above, just pick one, you're just introducing additional overhead which accomplishes the same thing in the end. if you already have fulltext indexes set just use match against

Comment: @Kevin and Your Common Sense, in my code I use AND between MATCH and LIKE arguments and between the different LIKE arguments to limit the number of results.

Comment: @Kevin I included the code for the search page and referenced the source code. Hope this help. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I did echo $sql and it print fine in the result page "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ( ? ) AND name LIKE ?". How I can troubleshoot the multi keywords combination. I feel there is a typo somewhere!

Comment: @MoussaEl-hallak this code is under the impression that multiple words means, `word1 word2 word3` and so on is the input, and then its exploded into an array with 3 elements inside as a payload to the actual starting code, so if its not the case, you can just convert it to be that way. the implementation is up to you

Comment: @Kevin I get an error with three keywords such as "word1 word2 word3". Surprisingly the code works fine with one keyword "word1". Not sure what is the issue but I suspect it has to do with the quotation mark inside AGAINST statement.  Can you help with the above error? Appreciate your help

Comment: Here is the error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? ?)) AND (name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?)' at line 1' in /11-search.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /11-search.php(39): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM T...') #1 /2-page.php(8): require('/Applications/A...') #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/AMPPS/www/php-mysql-search/11-search.php on line 39.

Comment: @MoussaEl-hallak im not sure how you're piecing out it all together, here's a sample scenario [fiddle](https://www.tehplayground.com/lZO2HesnmJQxyhBp)

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for the tip. Here are my two actual pages: https://www.tehplayground.com/UQSVRcraYu3RcvF0 and https://www.tehplayground.com/JizmKPR7fsEZEFfc